# GTK+ 3 StatusIcon replacement

Tags: gtk, gtk3, system-tray, trayicon

I want my GTK application to have a status icon in the system tray, I have got this working quite nicely using a [StatusIcon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html), however this has been deprecated:

> gtk_status_icon_new has been deprecated since version 3.14 and should not be used in newly-written code.
>
> Use notifications

The documentation says "Use notifications" but I have no idea what this actually means. I interpret this to mean "use desktop notifications", but as far as I can tell that serves an entirely different purpose. I want an always-visible system tray icon, not a temporary popup notification. Despite that, I can't find anything else which would seem to be what is meant by "Notifications".

Does there exist a new replacement for GtkStatusIcon which provides an icon in the system tray, with support for receiving mouse click/scroll signals and displaying popup menus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately yes, they refer to desktop notifications. If you still want to use system tray icons, then keep using GtkStatusIcon; just note that it is likely going to be removed soon. (The point is that more things have desktop notifications than status icons, but I'm sure there's other reasons as well. GTK+ probably shouldn't deal with desktop environment-specific stuff like that anyway... There's nothing stopping anyone from making a GtkStatusIcon replacement of their own, but no one seems to have done so yet.)

Comment: That's disappointing, I would have hoped GTK would make an effort to remain more versatile than that. I guess I'll just continue using GtkStatusIcon and hope an alternative arises before its removed. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: It's not going to be removed in GTK+ 3, but it might be removed in GTK+ 4, which is not backwards compatible. So you won't have to worry until you do migrate your code over, when that version of GTK+ comes around. It might be removed in a later version that that; I wouldn't know. As for versatility, GTK+ doesn't provide notifications either! You'd have to go to a separate library, such as libnotify, to do it.

Comment: That's true about notifications, I've primarily been using GTK with Python so I'm used to importing notifications along with GTK all from the GI API and that hadn't occured to me. I'll be interested to see how this is approached in future versions of GTK, though provided I can keep it working with GTK+ 3, that should do perfectly well for the time being.

Comment: It is already removed from Gtk4. Also AppIndicator is a valid replacement on desktops where tray icons are part of their design (KDE 5, Unity), They are not a part of Gnome design though.

Comment: Gtk+ 3 does have support for notifications through the `g_application_send_notification` API. However your application must be using `GApplication`/`GtkApplication`

Comment: Deprecating the status-icon is the worst decision ever made by Gtk. Notifications simply are not the same thing and simply do not provide what status icons do. The assumption that developers have mostly been using status icons for notifications is outright preposterous. They've mostly been using it to create utilities that you always want running and remain readily accessible, but don't want in your way. Notifications are completely and utterly useless for that kind of functionality.

Comment: Linux Mint has decided to implement their own fork of the GtkStatusIcon, named [XApPStatusIcon](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3795)

Answer (score 3):

For later versions of GTK+ 3, where StatusIcon is deprecated, you can use the following code to prevent seeing any warnings about deprecation:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
// Insert Status Icon Code Here
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

While it is deprecated, it was not removed from GTK until GTK4.

For GTK4 and others, I have created [TIL - Tray Icon Library](https://gitlab.com/jocez/til), which should work in any GTK version. There is example code how to use it with GTK4. Currently it only works using XCB via [XEMBED](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html), but more backends will be supported in the future. Long-term goal would be to support most of different backends to create tray/status icons in different circumstances.

Basically how it works is that, we create the tray icon completely using the backend we want, in this case X11. Then we get the X-Connection and X Window ID of the GTK Widget. Then we just add the X Window ID of the GTK Widget as the child of the tray icon we created using X. It makes it possible to insert any GTK Widget inside the tray icon. Tray icons in X are really just windows stuck in the tray. Not all widgets work thought.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ayatana-appindicator: https://github.com/AyatanaIndicators/libayatana-appindicator

it can replace StatusIcon